# Union of two arrays with Complex Numbers Elements

Tags: java

I have to do a program what can union two arrays with complex numbers elements. I defined my complex numbers class, assigned the complex numbers to array. The problem is i got stacked with writing a method what can union this two arrays. I know it could be done easely with collections but i need to solve this problem only using arrays, that's for my IT class. I'll put my code below, the comment line is where i need to implement the code. Im stacked with this problem for a long time. Please help me.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author Dragosh
 */
public class Multime {
//Here i assign values for complex numbers and asign them to arrays A and B
static Complex a1 = new Complex (4.0, 6.0);
static Complex a2 = new Complex (-2.0, 4.0);
static Complex a3 = new Complex (5.0, 7.0);
static Complex [] A = {a1,a2,a3}; 
static Complex b1 = new Complex (3.0, 6.0);
static Complex b2 = new Complex (-2.0, 4.0);
static Complex b3 = new Complex (-7.0, 5.0);
static Complex [] B = {b1,b2,b3};


//Here i define my union method with A and B arrays as arguments
public static Complex[] reuniune(Complex[] A, Complex[] B){
 int marime = A.length+B.length;//This is the length of the C array, A+B
 Complex[] C = new Complex[marime];//Here i assign the length to C array
 int i;
 int j;
 for(i=0;i<A.length;i++){//Here i go through my A array
 C[i]=A[i];//Here i assign A values to C values
 }
 for (j=0;j<B.length;j++){//Here i go through my B array
 //HERE I NEED TO WRITE THE CODE TO ASSIGN THE B VALUES TO C, WHICH ARE NOT IN A ARRAY
  }
 return C;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reuniune(A,B)));

    }

public static class Complex{ // Here is the definition of Complex numbers class
    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    public Complex(double real, double imag){
        re=real;
        im=imag;
    }

    public String toString(){ // Here is the converting the Complex class to string  
//like Real+Imaginary*i        
        if (im==0) return re + "";
        if (re==0) return im + "i";
        if (im<0) return re + "-" + (-im) + "i";
        return re + " + " + im + "i";
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this maybe, check for each element from B if it was in A:

```
for (j=0;j<B.length;j++){//Here i go through my B array
   boolean found = false;

   for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {    // check if element from B was already in A
      if (A[k].equals(B[j])) {       
          found = true;
          break;
      }
   }

   if (!found) {           // if B[j] was not in A, add it to C
      C[i] = B[j];
      i++;
   }
}
```

You need to implement your `equals` method for this to work. Maybe something simple like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Complex) {
        return this.im == ((Complex) o).im && this.re == ((Complex) o).re;
    } else {
        return super.equals(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not good because we loose two elements from A array, (4.0, 6.0) and (5.0, 7.0)

Comment: you need to implement `equals()` for your `Complex` class.

Comment: I tested it, it works with the code i posted. Just implement the `equals`

Comment: Yeah it works, but value (-2.0, 4.0i) is added two times in the C array instead one time

Comment: because you don't have your equals :P Do you?^^

Comment: It works perfectly with implementing equality in complex class. Thank you very much, you are guru !

Comment: I would add rating to your answer but i don't get enough rating by myself :(

Answer (score 0):

the pbm is that C indexes don't match. Here is the soluton :

```
public static Complex[] reuniune(Complex[] A, Complex[] B) {
        int marime = A.length + B.length;// This is the length of the C array,
                                            // A+B
        Complex[] C = new Complex[marime];// Here i assign the length to C array
        int i;
        int j;
        int k=0;
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {// Here i go through my A array
            C[k] = A[i];// Here i assign A values to C values
            k++;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {// Here i go through my B array
            // HERE I NEED TO WRITE THE CODE TO ASSIGN THE B VALUES TO C, WHICH
            // ARE NOT IN A ARRAY
            C[k] = B[j];
            k++;
        }
        return C;
    }
```